# Is it possible to hide a sheet using excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a scenario to hide the sheet based on the cell's value. Using the macro below I can able to achieve this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If [G1] = "Yes" Then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
  Else
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Since I need to fill some more data using OpenXML, after saved the file using OpenXML the macro causes the security error.

So it is possible to hide a sheet by a cell's selected value using excel formula ?

Comment: Ultimately, Excel formula belongs to the Cell or Cells so that in other words I can say Yes on the basis of the Formula's result (which is a cell value) you can Hide or unhide one or multiple worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

> So it is possible to hide a sheet by a cell's selected value using excel formula ?

### NO, it is not possible.

Excel formulas affect only the value of the cell in which they are entered. They can't affect anything else (other cell, sheet ...)